# How to read specific rows from excel file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel file and I need to extract certain data from the rows of a certain sheet. So far I have

```
import pandas as pd
xl_file = pd.ExcelFile((xlfilePath)
dfs = {sheet_name: xl_file.parse(sheet_name) for sheet_name in xl_file.sheet_names}
```

Now I would like to read the numerical values found in a particular row. The row structure is something like:

```
Length (mm) 10.1 - 16.0 - 19.5 - 16.4 - 11.3
```

where I am attempting to show what is in each cell of a row. The dashes indicate an empty entry in a cell! How can I read in a row like this using the pandas library? I happen to know what row number the above row has but would there be a way for pandas to look through the data frame and find the entry `length (mm)` instead of having to specify the row number?

Edit: The actual df.loc['length (mm)'] as suggested by EdChum looks like this:

```
0              17.92377
Unnamed: 1          NaN
0.05           18.55764
Unnamed: 3          NaN
0.1            19.17039
Unnamed: 5          NaN
0.15            19.7507
Unnamed: 7          NaN
0.2            20.29776
Unnamed: 9          NaN
0.25           20.80492
Unnamed: 11         NaN
0.3             21.2667
Unnamed: 13         NaN
0.35           21.67687
Unnamed: 15         NaN
0.4            22.02884
Unnamed: 17         NaN
0.45            22.3156
Unnamed: 19         NaN
0.5            22.53051
Unnamed: 21         NaN
0.55           22.66691
Unnamed: 23         NaN
0.6            22.71949
Unnamed: 25         NaN
0.65           22.68477
Unnamed: 27         NaN
0.7            22.56162
Unnamed: 29         NaN
0.75           22.35258
Unnamed: 31         NaN
0.8            22.06432
Unnamed: 33         NaN
0.85            21.7079
Unnamed: 35         NaN
0.9            21.29801
Unnamed: 37         NaN
0.95           20.85419
Unnamed: 39         NaN
1                20.394
Name: length (mm), dtype: object
```

Comment: can you post what the df looks like, are you saying that your index value is 'Length (mm)'? if so then won't `df.loc['Length (mm)']` work?

Comment: @EdChum Yes please see my edit. How can load this into a numpy array?

Comment: If you want a np.array from this then just do `df.loc['length (mm)'].values`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After loading your df you can select a specific row using label indexing `loc`:

```
df.loc['length (mm)']
```

If you want a np.array from this just do:

```
df.loc['length (mm)'].values
```

Answer (score 0):

While reading the file you can always specify the column name in the form of parameter to data frame.

```
import pandas as pd
fields = ['employee_name']

d_frame = pd.read_csv('data_file.csv', skipinitialspace=True, usecols=fields)
# get the required key or column name
print(d_frame.keys())
# Get data from column name
print(d_frame.employee_name)
```

I assumed `employee_name` would be the column name that you want to fetch the value from.